# How to show quick launch items for Anonymous users?

Tags: permissions, navigation, quick-launch, anonymous-authentication

I have an issue with the quick launch with regards to anonymous users.  I have set up my web application and site to allow anonymous read access.  All of the libraries, lists, and subsites have this enabled as well.  My problem is that none of the links to any pages or libraries in the quick launch appear for the anonymous users - they do appear for authenticated users.  Why is this and how can I fix it?  I have googled the heck out of this issue and apparently I'm the first one to ever have it, so hopefully someone can help and soon!

Thanks,

- Matt

Comment: The quick launch is security trimmed so I would look to find out what other conditions might cause them to be hidden.  Is your site a publishing site? Is it possible pages aren't published or approved?  Were you able to confirm an anonymous user could access the pages that should be showing up in the nav?

Comment: everything is published and/or approved. anonymous can go to sub sites, main page, sub pages, but cannot see links to libraries, or to the list of libraries

Comment: I wonder if the anonymous users don't have permissions to view the library form page even if they have access to list items. Can anonymous users access the libray or list of libraries if you type it directly in the browser? Are there images in the default library view?  If the image itself isn't published, it could also cause an access denied.

Comment: Yes, they can access individual libraries from a direct link.  The list of libraries (and Lists) is not available to them for perusal, though.  It logs me in as my windows account at the point when I click that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link out for instructions to see if ViewFormsPages lockdown is enabled:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/01/13/can-t-access-a-list-on-an-anonymous-site-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set Target Audience Property from SiteSettings->Navigation and set user group

Comment: No audiences are set.  What user group is "anonymous user" in?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive IF you remove view Item from permission they cannot see the links and subsites links .